# Bind list of string to listbox with datatemplate

Tags: c#, data-binding, windows-8, listbox, app-store

Hi I need bind data to listboxx with datateplate in listbox but I get this: **System.Colllections.Generic.List´1[System.String]** instead of a list of items.

```
<ListBox x:Name="lbMenu" ItemsSource="{Binding MyDataForLunchGrid}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock x:Name="tbMenu" Text="{Binding vydajnaMenus}"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="tbMenuNumber" Text="{Binding vydajnaNumber}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

**Data binding:**

```
_myDataForLunchGrid.Add(new BindingData
{             
    vydajnaMenus = Vydajna1Menus.Select(s => s.ToString()).ToList(),
    vydajnaNumber = "01"
});
OnPropertyChanged("MyDataForLunchGrid");
```

**MyCollection in mainpage**

```
  private ObservableCollection<BindingData> _myDataForLunchGrid = new ObservableCollection<BindingData>();

    public ObservableCollection<BindingData> MyDataForLunchGrid
    {
        get { return _myDataForLunchGrid; }
        set { _myDataForLunchGrid = value; }
    }
```

**Class BindingData**

```
public List<string> vydajnaMenus { get; set; }
public string vydajnaNumber { get; set; }
```

Any idea why I get System.Colllections.Generic.List´1[System.String] instead of a list of items.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I get it to work. Its not ideal solution but work great.

```
                foreach (var myVar in Vydajna1Menus)
                {  
                _myDataForLunchGrid.Add(new BindingData
                {
                    vydajnaMenus = myVar,
                    vydajnaNumber ="0"+numberOfFood.ToString()
                });
                }
                OnPropertyChanged("MyDataForLunchGrid");
```

Answer (score 0):

I you want to show collection of strings in individual list item, then you need to some how concatenate the strings. Otherwise the runtime will simply call the ToString() on the object.

I think the simplest way is to write a Converter which will concatenate strings in any collection.